# Log in to Salesforce CRM using Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0, salesforce

Have you tried to log in to Salesforce CRM using a Flutter Application? I'm using Oauth2 package (https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2/example) and Resource Owner Password Grant but it has some errors. Here the _login() method:

```
    Future<void> _login() async {
    final authorizationEndpoint =
        Uri.parse('https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize');

    // The user should supply their own username and password.
    final username = 'tqtai@cts.com.vn';
    final password = 'anhtak@1234SYxVnDtJBIucYIZN7jhbdd7Fr';

    final identifier = '3MVG9YDQS5WtC11rWdcCAUYsljvKVu5IzgImWYMf_7GjORIztH1G_pO8GDxX4P3r6mSw3kZknaQ6W5C';
    final secret = 'B3E1C3349AAFEB99A98E29A9F7CB3D8F7B56A62B640651F0869F74A0A2B092';

    var client = await oauth2.resourceOwnerPasswordGrant(
        authorizationEndpoint, username, password,
        identifier: identifier, secret: secret);

    File('~/.myapp/credentials.json').writeAsString(client.credentials.toJson());
    print('asdasdas');
}
```

and here is the error:

```
E/flutter ( 6464): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid OAuth response for "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize": Content-Type was "null", expected "application/json".
E/flutter ( 6464):
E/flutter ( 6464): error=unsupported_response_type&error_description=response%20type%20not%20supported
E/flutter ( 6464): #0      handleAccessTokenResponse
package:oauth2/src/handle_access_token_response.dart:98
E/flutter ( 6464): #1      resourceOwnerPasswordGrant
package:oauth2/src/resource_owner_password_grant.dart:86
E/flutter ( 6464): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6464): #2      _LoginScreenState._login
package:sf_clone_flutter/login/login.dart:116
E/flutter ( 6464): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6464):
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I _really_ hope those are not real Salesforce credentials in your post. If they are, change your password now and revoke all active sessions/OAuth grants.

Comment: Same for your Connected App Id and secret. Revoke and replace them.

Comment: I have already edited it, thank you. But don't worry, it's just a Developer Edition, so I don't have any problem with the security.

Comment: Please try using 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token' for endpoint as mentioned here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm

Comment: @VinodRondla It caused the error:
`E/flutter ( 8973): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: OAuth authorization error (unsupported_grant_type): grant type not supported.`

Comment: Looks like the grant type is always set to password in the implementation. You have to set basicAuth to false so that the client_id and client_secret are set in the request body. Please see the implementation for more details: https://pub.dev/documentation/oauth2/latest/oauth2/resourceOwnerPasswordGrant.html